# Why object replace instead update in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I am working on some chat - app whith complex messages. 
Messages from API stored in realm DB.

When i getting messages: call after API response, deserialization finished, messages correct:

```
 realm.beginTransaction();
 realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(listOfBaseMessageResponses);
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

messages in db replaced and i forced to make a List in my activity and try to handle changes by myself.

Changes tracked in activity by:

```
messagesChangedListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
...
}
mBaseMessageResponsesRealm = realm.allObjects(BaseMessageResponse.class);
mBaseMessageResponsesRealm.addChangeListener(messagesChangedListener);
```

Way to get messages:

```
return realm.allObjects(BaseMessageResponse.class);
```

`BaseMessageResponse` class(getters and setters exists. for better understanding not show):

```
    @SerializedName("clr")
    @Expose
    @PrimaryKey
    private String clr;
    @SerializedName("cap")
    @Expose
    private String cap;
    @SerializedName("eoc")
    @Expose
    private int eoc;
    @SerializedName("list")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<MessageInResponse> list = new RealmList<MessageInResponse>();
...
```

Also `MessageInResponse` contain nested classes.

Why messages replaced? I try many ways to figure it out but no result.

May be some problems with PK and logic for `copyToRealmOrUpdate` method?

Comment: Do the messages have their primary keys replaced?

Comment: @aelimill, primary keys in messages from api same for old messages and new for new messages. Actually i have one class from API: BaseMessageResponse that contains lists of messages  RealmList<MessageInResponse>. In case of get only new messages in chat: in realm after api call stored only new messages. Old is gone.

Comment: When you call `copyToRealmOrUpdate` all the objects in `list` will also be updated. That means the list will be replaced with new data, not that new messages will be added to the old list.